# Tooltip with text and image (javascript / css / html)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to combine both text and image in a set of tooldtips as text placed right next to an image in each tooltip box. Any ideas will be profoundly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what kind of tooltip are you using ? if you are relying on the title attribute for text tooltips then i guess you better use some plugin to achieve this. http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-tooltip/ might help

Answer (score 0):

The easiest would probably be to use jQuery and a tooltip plugin like [Simpletip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/simpletip/) but there are [plenty of others](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/stylish-jquery-tooltip-plugins-webdesign/http://craigsworks.com/projects/simpletip/).
There's other libraries too that don't require jQuery, like Skinnytip, etc.